# Loop should not break on encountering a invalid statement

Tags: javascript, html

Check out this code...

HTML

```
<span>TEST </span>

<div style="color:red">COlured div</div>
<div style="color:blue">COlured div</div>
<p style="color:red">Colourful TExt</p>
<p style="color:blue">Colourful TExt</p>
<p style="color:green">Colourful TExt</p>
<p style="color:brown">Colourful TExt</p>
<button onclick="changetobw()">CHANGE COLOR</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function changetobw() {
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    b = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var i = 0;
    do {
        a[i].classList.add('nocolor');
        b[i].classList.add('nocolor');
        i++;
    } while (i < a.length && i < b.length);   
}
```

CSS

```
.nocolor {
    color:#000 !important;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A52Lj/1/)

What i am attempting to do here is on click of the button make all the div and span font color "black".

My code breaks(obviously) when the counter crosses i=2 because there are just 2 div and hence "i[2]" would be undefined and hence the loop breaks.

Is there anyway for the loop not to break after hitting this point? Maybe I am not getting my point perfectly across. Hope you all understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the loop like you use it, you *have* to make sure both arrays have the same length.

Obviously, their length isn't equal, so either you seperate this one loop into two loops (1) or you go for two if-statements checking i against the length of both arrays (2). Even better would be using `for` in combination with the `querySelectorAll` (3).

(1):

```
function changetobw() {
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    b = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var i = 0;
    do {
        a[i].classList.add('nocolor');        
        i++;
    } while (i < a.length);   
    i = 0;
    do {
        b[i].classList.add('nocolor');
        i++;
    } while (i < b.length);
}
```

(2) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FW95/)):

```
function changetobw() {
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    b = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var i = 0;
    do {
        if(i < a.length)
          a[i].classList.add('nocolor');

        if(i < b.length)
          b[i].classList.add('nocolor');

        i++;
    } while (i < a.length || i < b.length);   
}
```

(3) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn8NP/)):

```
function changetobw() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('p, div');
  for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els.item(i).classList.add("nocolor");
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest _author_ to use 2 loops but there is also a (3) http://jsfiddle.net/A52Lj/2/ if he wants 1 loop.

Comment: I tried the 2nd option in a fiddle, does not work... whats the 3rd option with concat? i thought that was for string. Can u demo this for me in a fiddle?

Comment: @lancemanfv, you fiddle works neat. Why dont you post it as solution

Comment: @MarsOne added a fiddle for (3), the fiddle for (2) is nearly the same as lancemanfvs one

Comment: +1 for your answer, I would have definitely marked your answer as solution however (2) does not work...

Comment: @MarsOne, it is pretty the same as (2) + it is better to have all 3 in one answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not worried about browsers beneath IE9, you should use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead as this will allow you to pick up both types of element in the same query.

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('p, div');
for (var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++){
    a[i].classList.add('nocolor');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w94Bg/3/)

Answer (score 2):

I think u should make a specific generic method to change the color and then call it for each tag type  u need rather then changing all in one
try this :

```
function changetobw() 
{ 
    changeColor(document.getElementsByTagName('p'));
    changeColor(document.getElementsByTagName('div')) ;
}
function changeColor(obj)
{
    var i = 0;
    do {
        obj[i].classList.add('nocolor');
        i++;
    } while (i < obj.length);
}
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/A52Lj/5/

Comment: +1 for the attempt. But this diifers way too far from my original attempt

Answer (score 1):

This do the trick (maybe there is a more elegant solution)

```
function changetobw() {
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    b = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var i = 0;
    do {
        a[i].classList.add('nocolor');
        i++;
    } while (i < a.length);
    i = 0;
    do {
        b[i].classList.add('nocolor');
        i++;
    } while (i < b.length);

}
```

Comment: I already have that in another of my fiddles. I want it to happen in one. http://jsfiddle.net/A52Lj

Answer (score 1):

Another approach found :

```
function changetobw() {
  a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  b = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var j=(a.length>b.length)?a.length:b.length;

  var i = 0;
  do {
    if(i<a.length){
      a[i].classList.add('nocolor');
     }
     if(i<b.length){

         b[i].classList.add('nocolor');
     }

      i++;

   } while (i <j);

}
```

Comment: Buddy, it has a bug. If i increase no of div's to 5, it fails for the 5th div http://jsfiddle.net/A52Lj/3/

Comment: Yupe, after looking all answer i thought let us try other way to do that reducing the code and some logic adding and found this. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: The answer which you have accepted, the person copied answer from all answers given below and made that answer :(

Comment: Dude, what are you saying man. Don't get jealous or be hateful on SO. The person whose solution i accepted is the first person to answer my question. Check your attitude buddy, your solution is very very good. But dont have the crab mentality of pulling others down

Comment: Not pulling dear,but what you have accepted is corrected because whenever someone will see that answer will get all the approaches